# OpenLayers: WFS request to GeoServer to retrieve "name" & "featureNS"

Tags: geoserver, wfs, geometry, openlayers-2, describe-feature-type

Using `WFSGetCapabilities` I sent a `GetCapabilities` request to GeoServer. From the result of `WFSGetCapabilities().read()`, I can loop each featureType and retrieve some basic info (e.g., name, title, featureNS, srsName). Then in order to retrieve the `"geometryName"` property of this feature type, (which is needed to load this featureLayer into map), I sent a `DescribeFeatureType` request to server by attaching `"&TypeName="feature.name`. However, I found that the full name of the feature is truncated, i.e., `feature.name` is the feature's name without its namespace prefix. However, this namespace prefix is needed in DescribeFeatureType request URL.

My question is:

How can I get the full name (with namespace prefix) in order to execute this DescribeFeatureType request and retrieve the geometryName property?

Comment: Can you provide examples of actual values returned by GetCapabilities?

Comment: Were you able to obtain the solution for this? Could you post it here?

Comment: @Sam007: it was a long time ago. i tried: 1) wfsServerURL + '/ows?service=wfs&version=' + wfsServiceVersion + '&request=GetCapabilities'; parse its response, you will find responsibilities.featureTypeList.featureTypes[i] has several properties: name, full name,title, srs, featureNS etc. 2) service_url + '/ows?service=wfs&version=' + version +'&&request=DescribeFeatureType&TypeName=' + full_name; here using full name.

Comment: @Simon thanks for the reply. I also worked on it and found a better way using WMS itself. Here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34336/how-to-obtain-the-feature-attributes-from-feature-collection/34375#34375

Comment: @Sam007 not so sure that's a same question from the link you attached. but as long as you found a solution, thats good.

Answer (score 2):

> However, this namespace prefix is needed in DescribeFeatureType request URL.

You don't need to specify a TypeName in a DescribeFeatureType request, so you don't need a namespace.  If you omit the TypeName parameter you get all types represented by the service.

And these responses will give you the TypeName with their namespace prefix, for example:

http://geoserver.cprm.gov.br/geoserver/CPRM_EN_Bedrock_and_Age/ows?SERVICE=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&

or

http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_GSI_EN_Bedrock_and_Structural_Geology/ows?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0&