# How to Obtain the feature attributes from feature collection

Tags: openlayers-2, layers, fields-attributes

I am able to obtain the features of the layer which is selected by the user in the Layers table and then intersected by a user defined polygon, using `e.features`. I was able to obtain the attribute values of the feature as a property, like this `e.features[0].attributes.Family` or `e.features[0].attributes.Species`. The `e.features[0].attributes` object looks like this, `Object { Family="Pinaceae", Species="Pinus cembroides"}`.

Now the problem that I am facing is when a user selects a different layer, say `states`, the `attributes` properties change, the object now looks like this,
`Object { STATE_NAME="Arizona", STATE_FIPS="04", SUB_REGION="Mtn", more...}`. So now I need to fetch the attribute data by again changing the properties, like `e.features[0].attributes.STATE_NAME`.

So I am trying to create a common function where I can obtain the properties of the attributes object and then directly fetch the values for any layer. This is the code that I am trying to implement,

```
var attrData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < e.features.length; i++) {
    //Work on how to fetch properties for all the layers attributes
    feat = e.features[i];
    for (prop in feat.attributes) { alert(prop); } //this gives all the property values
    var values = "";
    for (prop in feat.attributes) {
      value = (value === "") ? feat.attributes.prop : value += feat.attributes.prop; //But feat.attributes.prop is undefined

    }
  attrData.push([value])
}
```

As you can see, `for (prop in feat.attributes) { alert(prop); }` gives me all the property names but when I assign this `prop` to `feat.attributes.prop` to fetch the value, it returns `undefined`.

Not sure where am I going wrong? This is my application, `http://128.196.142.12/geo/test/test_new.html`. Click on the 'draw poly' in the toolbar and then select 'Pima Pine' layer in the Map Layers column and create a polygon and intersect it with the blue stars (Pima Pine), you should get the table with the info of the stars which intersect with the vector polygon. Now I am trying to replicate the same for the USA States and that is where I am failing.

How should I change the code to fetch the attribute values for all the layers?

Comment: Sam, I am needing to do something you did. I would like your guidance. I need to get the features of a polygon created by the user. These features appear under the active / visible layers. You did it using something besides OpenLayers? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the current question. If you have a new question you should post it again, and link back here if you think it's related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
feat.attributes[prop]
```

Comment: Thanks, did not think it would be that easy. :)